# Is it possible to shorten the code for the DataStore Preferences

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow, android-jetpack-datastore

**Problem** - repeating piece of code when using **DataStore Preferences** and **Kotlin Flow**.
What Im talking about:

```kotlin
override fun readSomeData(): Flow<String> {
     return dataStore.data
         .catch { exception ->
             if (exception is IOException) {
                 emit(emptyPreferences())
             } else {
                 throw exception
             }
         }
         .map { preferences ->
             preferences[PreferencesKey.someValue] ?: "null value"
         }
}
```

Is it possible to put the functionality inside the **.catch { exception }** in a separate function, with the ability to change Kotlin Flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `suspend` extension function on `FlowCollector` type and reuse it:

```
suspend fun FlowCollector<Preferences>.onCatch(exception: Throwable) {
    if (exception is IOException) {
        emit(emptyPreferences())
    } else {
        throw exception
    }
}

fun readSomeData(): Flow<String> {
    return flow<String>{}
        .catch { 
            onCatch(it) 
        }.map { preferences ->
            preferences[PreferencesKey.someValue] ?: "null value"
        }
}
```

---

Or if you want to reuse the whole `catch` statement you can create an extension function on `Flow`:

```
fun Flow<Preferences>.onCatch() = catch { exception ->
    if (exception is IOException) {
        emit(emptyPreferences())
    } else {
        throw exception
    }
}

fun readSomeData(): Flow<String> {
    return flow<String> {}
        .onCatch()
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[PreferencesKey.someValue] ?: "null value"
        }
}
```